# Selecting Faces in a list, maya python

Tags: python, maya

I'm working on a script that will find tri's and nGon's on an object and select them. But when I store the faces in a list and try to select them I get this as a result.

[u'pCube1.f[2]']

How do I change that to make it just

[pCube1.f[2]]

Comment: It is storing them as a unicode strings. You need to supply more information (such as the code that produces the list) so that we can help you more.

Comment: correct, in the maya cmds python api the input and output of commands is usually a string representing the (partial) dag path of the object in question.  If you want a more object-oriented approach you could look at something like [pymel](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/index.html#!).

Answer (score 3):

most of the time maya returns the results of commands as lists of strings. They are unicode strings ( u'xxx') but that's OK - Maya accepts those interchangeably with regular strings: you can safely ignore the Unicode-ness of the strings and you don't need to go out of your way to make your own strings into Unicode. Maya will treat `['xxx']` and `[u'xxx']` interchangeably.

Selecting faces supports a couple of forms:

```
 #lists
 my_faces = ['pCube1.f[1]', 'pCube1.f[2]']
 cmds.select(my_faces)

 # tuples
 more_faces = ('pCube1.f[3]', 'pCube1.f[4]')
 cmds.select(more_faces, add=True)

 # direct selection:
 cmds.select('pCube1.f[5]', 'pCube1.f[6]')
```

To get all the faces in an object you can use the shortcut

```
 cmds.select('pCube1.f[*]')
```

or a range:

```
 cmds.select('pCube1.f[2:4]')
```

Maya will sometimes return compacted names like `pCube1.f[2:4]` as well.  You can split these out into individual items with the `filterExpand` command:

```
 print cmds.filterExpand('pCube1.f[1:5]', sm=34)
 # [u'pCube1.f[1]', u'pCube1.f[2]', u'pCube1.f[3]', u'pCube1.f[4]', u'pCube1.f[5]']
```

('sm = 34' is Maya-speak for 'faces only').

Biggest thing to watch out for is commands that return `None` where you would expect an empty list.  If you run into errors like `NoneType is not iterable` its probably a case of Maya returning `None` instead of `[]`.  You can usually get out of this by using 'or':

```
 item = cmds.ls("your_name_here") or []
```

which returns and empty list.

Comment: How can you invert the current face selection?

Comment: `cmds.select("myobject.f[*]", tgl=True)`